# Using alternate font styles in a photoshop script

Tags: javascript, text, fonts, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm writing a script for photoshop in Javascript to read from a list of words in a .txt document one at a time, add them to the image, export and then move onto the next word etc. Thats all well and good but I need to use an alternate style of the font, specifically I need to use single story "a" (circle with a line on the right) rather than the default a (circle with a curvy part on top), Is there a way to specify which stylistic set to use for the font within the script? You can do this within photoshop itself by clicking "Stylistic Alternates" in the type settings part of the text layer properties.

EDIT TLDR: I need my JS Photoshop script to use a stylistic alternate of a font, [this setting here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwv8Y.png). How can I do this in the script?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unless you explicitly set what font to use, there is no way Photoshop could do that. But... you could write your own own plugin that would identity different variations of the same character.

Answer (score 0):

I think achieving this via script will be a major pain. It may be possible using Action Manager scripting and the cryptic code generated by ScriptListener.

Maybe you'll be better off simply setting on a different font altogether.